# I need to loop this using XSLT code?

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, foreach

Im having a hard time looping this.

XML CODE:

```
    <ProcessData>
    <Messages>
        <MessageIds/>
        <MessageNames>
            <MessageName>tpname1_abc.txt</MessageName>                
            <MessageName>tpname2_def.txt</MessageName>
            <MessageName>tpname3_pqr.txt</MessageName>
            <MessageName>tpname4_xyz.txt</MessageName>
        </MessageNames>
    </Messages>
</ProcessData>
```

XSLT CODE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    Invalid File Received for Enrollments Inbound process in mailbox /sftptps/enrollments/deadletter


                <xsl:for-each select="/ProcessData/Messages/MessageNames/MessageName">
                      Username: <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(/ProcessData/Messages/MessageNames/MessageName/text(),'_')"/>       File Name:<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/ProcessData/Messages/MessageNames/MessageName/text(),'_')"/>

                        <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my output so far:

```
Invalid File Received for Enrollments Inbound process in mailbox /sftptps/enrollments/deadletter



                      Username: tpname1       File Name:abc.txt
                      Username: tpname1       File Name:abc.txt
                      Username: tpname1       File Name:abc.txt
                      Username: tpname1       File Name:abc.txt
```

I need it to be like this:

```
Invalid File Received for Enrollments Inbound process in mailbox /sftptps/enrollments/deadletter



                      Username: tpname1       File Name:abc.txt
                      Username: tpname2       File Name:def.txt
                      Username: tpname3       File Name:pqr.txt
                      Username: tpname4       File Name:xyz.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure there is something I'm missing to loop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already there - don't start from the top. Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(/ProcessData/Messages/MessageNames/MessageName/text(),'_')"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'_')"/>
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/ProcessData/Messages/MessageNames/MessageName/text(),'_')"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'_')"/>
```

---

What you have now selects **all** `MessageName` nodes, starting from the document's root and - in XSLT 1.0 - returns the value of the first one.

Comment: How would I put this into a table format? Two columns, 1. Username 2. File Name?

Comment: A "table format" could mean lot of a things. Please post the exact result (as code) you want to get.